# textprompt after button click in adaptive card doesnt invoke next step

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

Functionality:

1. Fetch and display relevant answer from QnAMaker
2. This response must be followed by an adaptive card with checkboxes
3. Based on the values selected, invoke a web service to provide the user with required file links.
4. Display a feedback message 'Did this help?'
5. Direct the conversation flow based on user response.

Problem Statement: For the step 2 mentioned above, the button click is being handled at the bot.cs file and redirected to a new Dialog. 
Everything works fine until displaying the feedback message(which is again invoked from a new Dialog). However, after this text prompt the
next step is not called and exits with an error: `The given key 'dialogs' was not present in the dictionary.`

Why does it show that error without going to the next step?

bot.cs

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.Text != null)
        {
            if (!dc.Context.Responded)
            {
                // examine results from active dialog
                switch (dialogResult.Status)
                {
                    case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
                        switch (topIntent)
                        {
                            case ...
                        }

                        break;

                    case ...
                }
            }
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text))
        {
            await HandleSubmitActionAsync(turnContext, userProfile);
        }
    }
}

private async Task HandleSubmitActionAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, UserProfile userProfile)
{
    if (value.Type == "GetCredentials")
    {
        userProfile.credentialsCard = true;
    }

    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(HandleButtonDialog));
}
```

HandleButtonDialog:

```
public HandleButtonDialog(BotServices _services, UserProfile _userProfile) : base(Name)
{
    botServices = _services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_services));
    userProfile = _userProfile;

    var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
    {
        GetFeedbackStepAsync,
        FeedbackStepAsync,
        FeedbackResponseStepAsync,
    };
    AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(HBFeedbackDialog));
    AddDialog(new TextPrompt("userFeed"));
}

public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if...
    else if(userProfile.credentialsCard == true)
    {
        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(HandleCredentialsFeedbackDialog.Name);
    }
}
```

HandleCredentialsFeedbackDialog:

```
public class HandleCredentialsFeedbackDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    public HandleCredentialsFeedbackDialog(BotServices services, UserProfile _userProfile,string dialogId = null) : base(Name)
    {
        botServices = services ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        userProfile = _userProfile;

        // This array defines how the Waterfall will execute.
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            CredsValidate,
            GetFeedbackStepAsync,
            FeedbackStepAsync,
            FeedbackResponseStepAsync,
        };
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("userFeed"));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(HBFeedbackDialog, waterfallSteps));
        InitialDialogId = HBFeedbackDialog;
    }

    public async Task<DialogTurnResult> CredsValidate(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        VALIDATE THE CHECKBOX SELECTED VALUES
        ....

        //Invoke Web Service
        var qnaReuslt = await MakeBatchRequestCreds(stepContext.Context, finalSearchList.ToArray());

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync("userFeed", new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Did this help?")
        });
    }
}
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.RepromptDialogAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, DialogInstance instance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\ComponentDialog.cs:line 112
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\ComponentDialog.cs:line 106
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 196
   at AESAiLean.Dialogs.HandleButtonDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\...\Dialogs\HandleButtonDialog.cs:line 199
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 113
   at AESAiLean.AESAiLeanBot.HandleSubmitActionAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, UserProfile userProfile) in C:\Users\...\Bots\AESAiLeanBot.cs:line 361
```

Comment: Please remember to include a question in your post

Comment: Is `HandleSubmitActionAsync` meant to be called in response to an Adaptive Card's submit action? Remember that a submit action will send a message activity to the bot. Your code will call `HandleSubmitActionAsync` in response to anything but a message activity.

Comment: The dialog key error usually manifests itself when you are attempting to push a dialog onto the dialog stack without having registered it first. The way you register a dialog is by calling the `AddDialog` method, every dialog that you want to display must have a call to `AddDialog` that passes in a parameter (which is used as the key in the dialogStack dictionary), this parameter should also match the parameter you use when you call the dialog with `BeginDialogAsync` etc. In your case it looks like `HandleButtonDialog` is missing an `AddDialog` call.

Comment: You can read more about dialogs in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#using-dialogs) and [sequential conversation flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, you are right - since I was unable to handle button clicks in adaptive card, I have added HandleSubmitActionAsync method to set the flags and send to HandleButtonDialog. In this case, for displaying the file links, a new dialog is invoked await dc.BeginDialogAsync(HandleCredentialsFeedbackDialog.Name); where I have the text prompt

Comment: I am adding the dialogs as required in the bot.cs 
 _dialogs.Add(new HandleButtonDialog(services, userProfile));

Comment: updated my code with HandleButtonDialog constructor

Comment: What line is throwing the error? We need a lot more information to figure out what's going wrong. Please edit your post so that separate pieces of code are in separate code blocks instead of the same code block. And again, submit actions send message activities to the bot. You should only be calling `HandleSubmitActionAsync` when the activity's type is `message`. My latest blog post might help you understand: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: I get the error after displaying the prompt(step 1) in the HandleCredentialsFeedbackDialog. Error Message: The given key 'dialogs' was not present in the dictionary. I have edited the post as suggested by you.Also added the stack trace for error.Both the dialogs inherit ComponentDialog. HandleSubmitActionAsync is called only if ActivityType is Message, missed adding the loop while editing post - corrected it now, sorry for that

Comment: Do you see in the stack trace where it says the error is being thrown on line 199 in `HandleButtonDialog.BeginDialogAsync`? Please provide *all* the relevant code. Also please debug your bot locally so you can step through the code and get more information about what's going on: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: Are you still working on this?